# Mysql - optimize table problems

Tags: mysql, zabbix

I am using the mysql database to run the zabbix server. I ran the follwing command to clear data older than 1 Jan 2022: delete from history_uint where clock < 1641006000;

This command was executed. But when I tried to run the: optimize table history_uint;

I am facing the following issue:

[image: optimize error]

Does anyone saw something like that?

Comment: Check if your disk is full.

Comment: Hi, I already checked, it seems ok, no partition is full.

Comment: But the optimize table operation uses extra disk space. You need enough free disk space to store both the original table and the optimized copy at the same time. Also it's possible for other temporary uses of disk space to interfere. I helped troubleshoot a site where a query created a very large temporary table, and when four of these queries ran concurrently, the whole disk volume ran out of space. But when they looked at the disk space a moment later, it was fine, because the queries finished and dropped their temp tables.

Answer (score 1):

Table is full --> Ran out of disk space.   By the time you looked, the extra space has been freed up.  (See Bill's Comment.)

Is `tmpdir` on a small disk partition?

Consider the following when doing big deletes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig